# I'm not able to send mail via mailgun using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, mailgun

I'm facing an issue to send email. I have my website built with Laravel. I have the files set up properly. That happens in 2 files.

The first one contains "driver" which of course is mailgun, "host" (smtp.mailgun.org), "port" (587 and according to my provider it's opened), "encryption" (tls), "username" and "password" (both with the right values).

The second one contains "domain" and "secret" (also both with the right values).

The domain is not the mailgun domain but my own domain, which is ACTIVE after set the Domain Verification and DNS.

The mailgun domain is still there ACTIVE. I don't know if I have to remove it or something. I really don't know what I'm missing here.

---

**IMPORTANT UPDATE**

```
Class 'GuzzleHttp\Client' not found
```

I'm receiving that message

---

**mail.php**

```
return array(

    'driver' => 'mailgun',

    'host' => 'smtp.mailgun.org',

    'port' => 587,

    'from' => array('address' => 'not-reply@xxxxxxxxx.com', 'name' => 'xxxxxxx'),

    'encryption' => 'tls',

    'username' => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",

    'password' => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",

    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

    'pretend' => false,

);
```

Obviously, the xxxxxxxxxx are my personal data. I can assure I'm setting the right values. It should work, indeed. :(

**services.php**

```
return array(

    'mailgun' => array(
        'domain' => 'domain-here',
        'secret' => 'key-here',
    ),

    'mandrill' => array(
        'secret' => '',
    ),

    'stripe' => array(
        'model'  => 'User',
        'secret' => '',
    ),

);
```

`domain` and `secret` are populated with the right values too.

Comment: try to require  `"guzzle/guzzle": "~3.9@dev"` directly from composer. And then test again

Comment: @manix how can I do that. I'm on a server

Comment: I have created an answer for this. Take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to require `guzzle` dependency directly.

1. Add `"guzzle/guzzle": "~3.9@dev"` to composer.json like, example:

   ```
   "require": {
       "laravel/framework": "5.0.*",
       "guzzle/guzzle": "~4.0"
   },
   ```
2. Update your project. The command below shoul be executed in a terminal/console. For example, if your laravel application is hosted in a windows machine, you do:

   ```
   > cd project/folder/path // change the working path
   > composer update // this command update the proyect and dependencies
   ```

   If you laravel is hosteed in a linux machine the you do:

   ```
   $ cd /path/a/mi/folder   // change the working path
   $ composer update   // this command update the proyect and dependencies
   ```
3. Test again your application

Comment: I don't understand the step #2. Is that on command prompt? I don't run command prompt on my hosting provider.

Comment: I'm having a hard time to get my hosting provider permission to perform that. I'll let you know as soon I solve that issue. BTW your code is not in english ?

Comment: I couldn't run the command remotely, but I did it locally and as the result of the updating operation, the guzzle dependency is now there. Then, I uploaded the added dependency to the remote server. However, the class is still missing either on local and on remote. I also tried to place the folder created after update in the namespace where the class is invoked. Still nothing.

Comment: I had this message after update: guzzle 5 has moved to a new package name. The package you have installed, guzzle 3, is deprecated.............Any idea?

Comment: Oh hehe, I combine my native lang with english: a twister lang xD. And I supose that you run your project under  L5 because I did not see the specific tag. But nice to know that everything goes good

Answer (score 1):

The @manix suggestion it seems to be the right approach but the version suggested `3.9` is deprecated. So it should be:

```
"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~4.0"
```

As I have the project built with **Laravel 4.2**.

It should be `5.0` for **Laravel 5.0**.